# Android Studio: Why is the spinner not displayed correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

It's about the spinner. He gets his data from an ArrayList, which gets your data from an http request. The http request is in json and is converted accordingly.

```
package de.it18b.saufomat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView mTextViewResult;

    ArrayList<String> tester;

    public MainActivity() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tester=new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            run("http://111.111.111.1/helloWorld");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }




    public void btnc1(View view) throws IOException {
        run("http://111.111.111.1/helloWorld");
    }
    public void btnc2(View view) throws IOException {
        run("http://111.111.111.1/helloWorld");
    }

    public void run(String url) throws IOException {
        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(myResponse);
                                String test0 = jsonObject.toString();
                                tester.clear();
                                tester.add(0,"Auswählen");

                                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    tester.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                                }

                                mTextViewResult.setText(test0);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });


        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tester);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

The problem is that the spinner doesn't show the content directly, although it is filled when the app is started. If I click on the little arrow the entries are inside but can't be selected. If I click on the button2 (Bestellen) again and execute the request (including inserting in the spinner), the first entry is displayed correctly and you can select other data.

Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks a lot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0rfg.png)

Attached is a video to help you understand the problem

https://puu.sh/GrWt0/b9cfca5f97.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an empty ArrayList add an item to arrayList, so that whenever spinner runs it has default selection. Then when the data fetch from remote and available in the spinner dropdown, if you select the spinner item it will select the item without being delayed.

example:

```
      List tester = new ArrayList<>();

      tester.add("Nothing selected");// or use empty String
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I already fill the ArrayList with such a "placeholder" entry?


`tester.add(0,"Auswählen");`